# Powershell script to split one column to two columns

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pull a report of processes sorted with count in a csv file.

Here I'm getting the output in csv file in a single column like below separated with space(part of output displayed)

```
$process0 = Get-Process
$process1 = $process0.ProcessName
$process1 | 
  Group-Object -NoElement | 
  sort Count -Descending |
  Format-Table |
  Out-File D:\Testing\process.csv
```

I need the output in separate columns for Count & Name in the csv file [first column for `Count` & second column for `Name`]. Can someone help in this ?

Output :

```
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
   86 svchost                  
   13 chrome                   
    1 rundll32                 
    1 Registry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$process0 = Get-Process 
$process1 = $process0.ProcessName 
$process1 | Group-Object -NoElement | sort Count -Descending | Format-Table |  Out-File D:\Testing\process.csv1
```

to this

```
$process0 = Get-Process
$process1 = $process0.ProcessName
$process1 | Group-Object -NoElement | sort Count -Descending | Select-object Name,Count |export-csv D:\Testing\process.csv -notypeinformation
```

You have used `Format-Table` this turns the output to text on a screen rather than the object that was in the pipeline with multiple properties. Take out the `Format-Table` and then use `Export-Csv`  rather than `Out-File`